# Why should we not use port 80 during development?

Tags: nginx

A colleague of mine recently pushed a change to the development config for our nginx. He changed the port from `8080` to `80`. It's a rather lazy fix for a development-only issue. I reviewed the change and challenged it, calling it not idiomatic for development. Now he's pushing me for more reasons why it's not ok. I think that's a completely reasonable line of enquiry but I am having difficulty understanding exactly why it's a bad idea -- maybe it isn't?

Things I have found:

- Port 80 is within the 'special' port range (< 1024) and therefore should be reserved for 'special' use (and development does not fall into this category).
- Historically, partially for the above reason, port 80 is reserved for "root" user and therefore running a daemon on port 80 would *imply* it has (or required) root priviledge, which isn't the case.

None of these cases are super compelling so is there anything else we should be aware of?

nginx is containerised

Comment: That ports < 1024 are reserved for root is not a historic limitation, it's still the case. You'd have to run your development nginx as root to bind to that port. Running development workloads as root is a bad idea, since misconfigurations could break the system. This probably doesn't matter if you're running nginx in a container though.

Comment: I have no idea why this question is being downvoted. Please can you elaborate in the comments?

Comment: @AntonyWoods Your question concerns software engineering practices, is concise, and is clear, so +1 from me. If anything, you might want to juggle a bit with your tags as they all seem to be quite inactive (I'm not sure which one would be better, but I'd at least remove [nginx] as it does not seem relevant to your question).

Comment: @amon: That's as good an answer as any.

Comment: @amon I would argue that running any server as root is a security risk.  It greatly increases the potential impact of a vulnerability.  The idea that doing it in development is somehow worse in than in production seems strange to me.

Comment: @JimmyJames: The principle there is that the development environment should be a "safe" one.  Why expose public ports unnecessarily?  This is, of course, also true of production environments, but the developer really shouldn't have to worry about being hacked in a development environment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Maybe I'm missing something but from what I can tell, a port needs to be exposed regardless.  The question is whether that port is bound to one that requires root access.  The 'right way', as I understanding it is to bind and then change the owner of the process to a user with [minimized privileges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).  I don't see why you couldn't do that in development.  I can understand why you wouldn't want to bother with that though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The potential issue with running on port 80 is that it's in the range that requires root access to bind to it (at least in *nix.)  The problem with running a server under root is that the impact of potential exploits is much higher.  For example a server with a [path traversal flaw](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal) could access the [shadow file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd#Shadow_file) if it's running with root privileges.

You should not be running your server with root/superuser privileges in any environment.  The user should be switched to something with [minimal privileges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) after binding if you need to bind to 80 or 443 etc.

If the user is switched to deprivilege the process in dev, I don't see any particular problem with running on 80.  If you don't want to do that in dev or can't enforce it, then that's your reason for restricting it.  I would just make sure your colleague and other team members understand the real issue is not so much the port number but the risks of running a server as root.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is enough for me to have another conversation with my team and discuss what we should do